# Properties on Address Book in AM

Tags: audience-manager

I need to manage my users into Country --> Accounts --> Contacts. Each country have different businesses. Different accounts within one country can have one/many businesses which are available for this country. And again Contacts within one account can be assigned to one or many businesses available in account.
if I need to fulfill this requirement completely using Audience management, I am not able to think of the complete solution. Here are the points which I am able to think

1. Let say we have one country , I will create Address Books for all the different accounts and these Address books can be assigned to Country Publication
2. Will create "keywords" for all the business and assign one/many keywords on Contacts

But as there is no option to assign keywords on Address Book , how can I assign businesses on account so that I can put a check that contacts within one account can only be assigned businesses which are available for this account.
I hope my question is in understandable form.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into using Dynamic Address Books for this?

I don't quite see the full picture of your setup, but you could have one static Address Book per country, assign whatever Keywords or Extended Details you need to the Contacts so that you can group them further, and then create Dynamic Address Books filtering on said fields/Keywords and assign them to the relevant Publications.

Would that solve your use case? If not, perhaps you could further explain the scenario and what the challenges are?

Answer (score 1):

Short of a full blown GUI extension or custom page - could you use the **Key** field of each Account address book to store a comma separated list of of *allowed* business keyword item ids?

The key may well have to be unique which may become an issue if an two accounts share the same business keywords.

Also, I don't think this information is available on the CD side - there's an `AddressBookId` as part of the `Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact` but that's it as far as I can see. THis may or may not be an issue depending upon your use case.

You'd need some other TBBs/templates/page to walk your address books on the CM side to create some kind of config file on your CD side for your application to use.

[image]

Comment: I realize you're just trying to be helpful and throw out ideas to solve the use case. But I hope nobody starts abusing the Key field for this kind of logic :) There's got to be a better way.

Comment: Agreed - as you've pointed out, more specific information required!